# Jasmine - DRY test cases - print custom result

Tags: jasmine

I am writing a Jasmine test (example simplified here), which needs to verify similar things.

lets say an object:

```
var obj = {
    apple: true,
    banana: true,
    grape: false,
    lemon: true
}
```

my test is to verify that all the properties of obj are true.

so I write:

```
it('should have all properties as true.', function(){
    for(var i in obj){
        expect(obj[i]).toBe(true);
    }   
})
```

Now, when this test is run, it will fail as grape is false. But, the output does not tell me which property (grape) failed.

I would like to customize the output so that it tells me that the grape property failed. So, I would like to do this:
Over-ride expect function somehow to print something like this:

```
Expected false to be true for grape
```

I know that i could loop these in a describe with individual 'it' blocks for each property. But, lets say that the the 'obj' Object becomes available only after an initialization in the beforeEach block and hence that is not an option for me.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a [*custom error message*](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/2752) this way:

```
for(var i in obj){
    expect(obj[i]).toBe(true, "Expected '" + obj[i] + "' to be true");
}
```

Comment: Great! This did the trick. Is this mentioned somewhere in Jasmine documentation? Don't seem to find it. But, thanks for the tip bro.

Comment: @Aneesh yeah, I don't think it's documented.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom matcher like this:

```
beforeEach(function () {
  jasmine.addMatchers({
    toBeAll: function () {
      return {
        compare: function (obj, expected) {
          var failedProps = [];
          for (var prop in obj) {
            if (obj[prop] != expected) {
              failedProps.push(prop);
            }
          }
          var result = {
            pass: true
          };
          if (failedProps.length > 0) {
            result.pass = false;
            result.message = "Expected '"+failedProps.join("' & '")+"' to be " + expected;
          }
          return result;
        }
      };
    }
  });
});

it('should have all properties as true.', function () {
  expect(obj).toBeAll(true);
});
```

Comment: Nice suggestion! But, seems a bit round about. I could however use this in some other situations. Thanks buddy.